# jQuery and .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and I need to keep objects through my plugin method calls. So I tried to use `.data()` as recommended here : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

but I'm unable to retrieve my stored objects, here my code :

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var settings = {
                    'geocodeSearch': {address: 'France'}
                };

                // Merge default settings with user ones
                if (options) {
                    $.extend(settings, options);
                }

                function drawMap(geocodeResult) {
                    var mapSettings = {
                        center: geocodeResult[0].geometry.location,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                        overviewMapControl: false,
                        panControl: true,
                        scaleControl: true,
                        streetViewControl: false,
                        zoom: 6,
                        zoomControl: true,
                        zoomControlOptions: { style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL }
                    };

                    var element = document.getElementById($this.attr("id"));
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapSettings);
                    var cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);

                    cluster.setGridSize(100);

                    $this.data('eventsmap', {
                        cluster: cluster,
                        map: map
                    });
                }

                    geocoder.geocode(settings.geocodeSearch, drawMap);
            });
        },
        restrictZoom : function(minimalZoom, maximalZoom) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                console.log($this.data());
                console.log($this.data('eventsmap'));

                //google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                //  if (map.getZoom() > maximalZoom) {
                //      map.setZoom(maximalZoom);
                //  }
                //  if (map.getZoom() < minimalZoom) {
                //      map.setZoom(minimalZoom);
                //  }
                //});
                //cluster.setMaxZoom(maximalZoom-1);
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.eventsMap = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.eventsMap' );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

When I call restrictZoom method, $this.data() (line 48) returns data from the DOM but if I try to get the 'eventsmap' attribute as set during the init method, I got undefined ($this.data('eventsmap') line 49).
I'm sure it's the right DOM object and my objects are because I can see them trhough my browser debugger :

[image: Chrome output]

I dunno what to do.

Edited : html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us" > 
<head> 
<title>Map tool | Django site admin</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" /> 

<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/ie.css" /><![endif]--> 

<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/earthquake/js/markerclusterer.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/earthquake/js/map.js"></script> 

<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" /> 
</head> 


<body class="eventsmap"> 

<!-- Container --> 
<div id="container"> 


    <!-- Header --> 
    <div id="header"> 
        <div id="branding"> 
        <h1 id="site-name">Events database</h1> 
        </div> 

        <div id="user-tools"> 
            Welcome,
            <strong>admin</strong>.



                    <a href="/admin/doc/">Documentation</a> /



                    <a href="/admin/password_change/"> 

                Change password</a> /


                    <a href="/admin/logout/"> 

                Log out</a> 

        </div> 


    </div> 
    <!-- END Header --> 

<div class="breadcrumbs"> 
<a href="/admin/">Home</a> &rsaquo; <a href="/admin/events">Events</a> &rsaquo; Map tool
</div> 





    <!-- Content --> 
    <div id="content" class="colM"> 



<div id="eventsmap" style="width: 100%;"></div> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mapCanvas = $("#eventsmap");

    // Cleanup and prepare HTML from Django
    $("#footer").remove();
    $("html").height("100%");
    $("body").height("100%");
    $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
    $("#content").css('margin', 0);
        mapCanvas.height($(document).height()-57);

    mapCanvas.eventsMap({
        geocodeSearch: {address: 'France'}
    });
    mapCanvas.eventsMap('restrictZoom', {
        minimalZoom: 2,
        maximalZoom: 9
    });
});
</script> 


        <br class="clear" /> 
    </div> 
    <!-- END Content --> 

    <div id="footer"></div> 
</div> 
<!-- END Container --> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `console.log($this)` when setting/getting the data to see if you actually access the same objects...

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me.  Perhaps if you included the code of how it's being called.

Comment: init and restrictZoom are used on the same object, and I use this plugin only on one object of my page. So I think it's the same this between init and restrictZoom because I add 'eventsmap' dict in init and saw it in restrictZoom method (but I'm Js beginner).

And I've just seen this bug open few hours ago on jQuery bugtracker : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8986

So I tried with the previous version (1.5.1) but I still have the same issue :/

Comment: I've just tried to add a console.log($this) in init and restrictZoom, there are the same object.

Comment: HTML added to show it's called.

Comment: try to use $.data($this[0], "test", yourdata) and $.data($this[0], "test")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why it didn't work, I had to ensure that plugin methods are synchronous called. To realize this, I wrap my methods in jQuery .queue function like this :

```
(function($) {
var methods = {
    init : function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).queue(function() {
                var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('eventsmap');
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var settings = {
                    'geocodeSearch': {address: 'France'}
                };

                // Merge default settings with user ones
                if (options) {
                    $.extend(settings, options);
                }

                function drawMap(geocodeResult) {
                    var mapSettings = {
                        center: geocodeResult[0].geometry.location,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                        overviewMapControl: false,
                        panControl: true,
                        scaleControl: true,
                        streetViewControl: false,
                        zoom: 6,
                        zoomControl: true,
                        zoomControlOptions: { style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL }
                    };

                    var element = document.getElementById($this.attr("id"));
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapSettings);
                    var cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);

                    cluster.setGridSize(100);

                    if (!data) {
                        $this.data('eventsmap', {
                            cluster: cluster,
                            map: map
                        });
                    }
                    $this.dequeue();
                }

                geocoder.geocode(settings.geocodeSearch, drawMap);
            })
        });
    },
    restrictZoom : function(args) {
        var minimalZoom = args.minimalZoom;
        var maximalZoom = args.maximalZoom;

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).queue(function() {
                var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('eventsmap');

                google.maps.event.addListener(data.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                    if (data.map.getZoom() > maximalZoom) {
                        data.map.setZoom(maximalZoom);
                    }
                    if (data.map.getZoom() < minimalZoom) {
                        data.map.setZoom(minimalZoom);
                    }
                });

                data.cluster.setMaxZoom(args.maximalZoom-1);

                $(this).dequeue();
            });
        });
    }
};

$.fn.eventsMap = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.eventsMap' );
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Now it works like a charm, I was calling myObject.data('eventsmap') before it was set in init method btw I'm still unable to explain why I could see the object in the browser ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Overall the code looks really good. But here are two ideas:

1. Have you tried to store a simpler object literal in that data function to ensure that to code works otherwise? You're currently storing a Google Map object and a MarkerCluster. Are those objects too complex to encode to json and store in a data attribute? (Can't remember if they are simply object literals or if they have functions and other elements in them as well)
2. Just a stylistic thing, but there are a number of reused names that make it harder to debug the code. (overall your code is great) There are two different variables named $this (in different scopes it looks like) and three items named eventsmap (a css class, a js variable and an extension function). While they're probably fine, it may trip up some folks reading over this code.

I hope that sparks some ideas!

Comment: you can store closures as values in the data map, so storing those 2 things should not be a problem